# Is there a conversion chart for items?

Tags: fallen-london

In Fallen London, there are a wide variety of currency-like items (indeed, it's part of the metaplot). Most of these can be converted into something else: many Whispered Secrets can be converted into a smaller number of Cryptic Clues, which can then become an even smaller number of Appalling Secrets, which can then convert further. For most of these conversions, they remain the same type: Whispered Secrets, Cryptic Clues, and Appalling Secrets are all *Mysteries*, for example.

The trouble is that some of these conversions result in items of different types.

For instance, Journals of Infamy (a *Mysteries* item) can be converted to Correspondence Plaques (a *Wild Words* item). This makes it difficult to tell whether I can get what I want. If I want, say, Favours In High Places, do I need to sell my stuff at the Bazaar in order to buy a different base-level item and then convert upwards (which is a bit inefficient), or do I have items already that I can convert into the final product?

**Is there a chart out there of how all of these currency-like items are converted into each other, and at what ratios?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Echo, divided into 100 pence, is the currency of the Bazaar. You can only obtain Echos through the Bazaar. And (so far) they are only useful to buy other kinds of items there.

Each set of items can really be break into belonging to one domain or another.

Example: Inferno items are associated with Hell.

The following link is the conversion chart with all the ratios and values.

http://echobazaar.wikidot.com/item-conversions

By clicking on the items you can see the events you can trigger resulting in random fortunes or misfortunes. You can click the spoilers to see what is possible to get.

The following quote is from the same link above and addresses your question about **converting categories**.

"The 50p item of each category converts into another category, at an exchange rate of 50:51. (One category, Mysteries, has two 50p items, Tale of Terror!! and A Journal of Infamy - so it appears twice in the below.)

For example you can create Whisper-Satin Scrap (3rd item - Rag Trade category) with Strangling Willow Absinthe (3rd item - Wines category)."

**Tier 3 Items**

Memory of Distant Shores

Brilliant Soul

Tale of Terror!

Compromising Document

Memory of Light

Zee-Ztory

Strangling Willow Absinthe

A Journal of Infamy

Correspondence Plaque

Vision of the Surface

Mystery of the Elder Continent

Incendiary Gossip